# zipline run_pipeline and positional arguments

Tags: python, zipline

I'm using Zipline-1.1.1, Python3.4.6 to create a dynamic stock selector as follows:

```
from zipline.pipeline import Pipeline, engine
from zipline.pipeline.factors import AverageDollarVolume, Returns

def make_pipeline():
    dollar_volume = AverageDollarVolume(window_length=1)
    high_dollar_volume = dollar_volume.percentile_between(N, 100)
    recent_returns = Returns(window_length=N, mask=high_dollar_volume)
    low_returns = recent_returns.percentile_between(0, n)
    high_returns = recent_returns.percentile_between(N, 100)
    pipe_columns = {
        'low_returns': low_returns,
        'high_returns': high_returns,
        'recent_returns': recent_returns,
        'dollar_volume': dollar_volume
    }
    pipe_screen = (low_returns | high_returns)
    pipe = Pipeline(columns=pipe_columns, screen=pipe_screen)
    return pipe
```

I initialize a pipeline object with:

```
my_pipe = make_pipeline()
```

But when I try to populate the Pipeline, it fails with:

```
result = engine.PipelineEngine.run_pipeline(my_pipe, '2017-07-10', '2017-07-11')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    result = engine.PipelineEngine.run_pipeline(my_pipe, '2017-07-10', '2017-07-11')
TypeError: run_pipeline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end_date'
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using [this](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/zipline/pipeline/engine.py) library.

As far as I can see from that code, to be able to use `run_pipeline` method you have to [instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396856/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python) on of pipeline engines before, e.g. `SimplePipelineEngine`. You need that because `PipelineEngine` is a class, even abstract class, not an object.

So you have to create an **object** of `SimplePipelineEngine` class and then call `run_pipeline` on it. You can do it this way:

```
your_engine = SimplePipelineEngine(get_loader=your_loader, calendar=your_calendar, asset_finder=your_asset_finder)
your_eninge.run_pipeline(my_pipe, '2017-07-10', '2017-07-11')
```

Of course you have to create `your_loader` etc. first.

[Here](http://programtalk.com/python-examples/zipline.pipeline.engine.SimplePipelineEngine/) is example of `SimplePipelineEngine` usage. I hope it will help.

Comment: Yes indeed it helps! Thank you.

Comment: Here is a deep dive into the offline implementation: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/911