# How to deal with the error "too many arguments" in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables

I try to make a Toy class here

```
class Toy:

  def __init__(self,name,ID,price,age):


    self.__ToyName = name  
    self.__ToyID = ID
    self.__Price = price
    self.__MinimumAge = int(age)
##some methods here
```

And when i try to make a sub-class computer game, i need to make 7 arguments(with 5 from the Toy class)to instantiating the computer game class, and it shows "too many arguements (7/5)"

```
class ComputerGame(Toy): 
  def __init__(self,name,ID,price,age,catogory,console):

    Toy.__init__(self,name,ID,price,age)
    self.__Catogory = catogory
    self.__Console = console
```

What should I do to with this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to instantiate a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396856/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)

Comment: `self.toy = Toy(name,ID,price,age)` or similar is what you want. Check the dup for more details.

Comment: I don't know what you did, because I see no problem in you code, and my python doesn't either...

Comment: I'd write `super().__init__(name, ID, price, age)` but be careful, `super` does not work like in other languages. Your code is correct, tho. You should just do `ComputerGame(name, ID, price, age, category, console)`

Comment: Also, unless you really know what you're doing and why, don't use class attribute names starting with a double underscore. See (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Answer (score 2):

you need learn more about `super`

```
class ComputerGame(Toy): 
  def __init__(self, name, ID, price, age, catogory, console):
    super(ComputerGame, self).__init__(name, ID, price, age)
    self.__Catogory = catogory
    self.__Console = console
```

Comment: There are information about [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super)

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean if I got a sub class with multiple variables I will have to use the `super` method? And how do I deal with class that itself has a very long list of variables?

Comment: There is no problem that you give a very long list of variables. However I have a little suggestion about parameters： 1. Whether need split to more class, 2. Maybe give some default parameter? 3. Use keywords parameters?

Comment: A blog about [super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)